# PHP strtotime() not working with first day of month

Tags: php, strtotime

for some reason, strtotime() is not working properly for me.

```
strtotime("first friday 2016-01") outputs 8.1.2016 instead of 1.1.2016

strtotime("first tuesday 2016-02") outputs 8.2.2016 instead of 1.2.2016
```

Am I missing something? Is the input wrong?

php version is: 5.4

Comment: `strtotime("first monday 2016-01")` give me `Monday 4th of January 2016`, which it is what i've expected.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant first friday. Just updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the keyword "of" is the solution,

strtotime("first friday **of** 2016-01") outputs 1.1.2016